# Send html email with images in django

Tags: django

I am using django 1.11 and trying to send HTML Email with Inline Images according to this [article](https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2014/01/15/sending-emails-with-embedded-images-in-django/)

my code is shown in blew:

```
html_content = render_to_string(
    settings.TEMPLATE_ROOT + "/foo.html",
)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('hello', html_content,
                             'John Foo <john@foo.com>', 
                             ['john@foo.com'])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'

for f in ['logo.jpg']:
    fp = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f), 'rb')
    msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
    msg.attach(msg_img)
msg.send()
```

and in html file i include image like:

```
<html> <img src="cid:logo.jpg" alt="logo"></html>
```

but the image not shown in received email.
Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you inspect the raw email? Is the image one of the multiparty and what’s it’s ID?

Comment: I checked original message, but there isn't content id in it :(

Comment: The image is there without Content-ID or the image is not there?

Comment: There isn't any 'content-id' or image in the header

Comment: in the header??? It's in the body you need to look, you should have a `--===============0527806758==` boundary (or similar) with the image below. The raw email should look like the one in the [link](https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2014/01/15/sending-emails-with-embedded-images-in-django/) you posted, maybe it would help if you show us here the full raw email as you see it.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by adding msg_img.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename=filename)